# Why is Mobile Broadband connection not shown in the Network Manager in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager, bluetooth

I have created a Mobile Broadband connection using Bluetooth in Ubuntu 12.04 but it is missing in the network manager icon on the top panel of the desktop.

How should I solve this problem? When I create a connection using DSL, it is displayed in network manager. But why it is not displaying for Mobile Broadband connection?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your pc or mobile ?!

Comment: Ya already tried this.. But not working..

Comment: I think it might be beneficial to know what kind of phone it is, and who your service provider is. Please edit your question to to reflect this information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use Bluetooth but connect your pc using USB modem instead since it may not be able to detect your mobile device.

Comment: While transferring/browsing a files it is working.. But why its not showing the networking connection with connection name..

Answer (score 0):

your cell phone modem is not compatible with Ubuntu.... most of these type of problem arises with nokia phones.

So there is only one way to come out if it is either you change your cellphone or you may get connected through USB wire.